# Getting Between data in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have Some Data in Mongodb Collection...I  need data From Activity equals to Login and Activity equals to Logout how to Achieve this....I have attached sample data please find and Help me...
                            Thank You

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac31dae7201801adcddc1a1"),
"User" : "7829780519",
"Activity" : "Login",
"Date" : "2018-04-03",
"Time" : "11:52:36.716Z",
"LocationDetails" : "Banashankari 3rd Stage, Banashankari, Bengaluru, 
 Karnataka, India"
 }
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac335df9c1cb11f28595d47"),
"User" : "7829780519",
"Activity" : "Tracking",
"Date" : "2018-04-03",
"Time" : "13:35:51.237Z",
"LocationDetails" : "Banashankari 3rd Stage, Banashankari, Bengaluru, 
 Karnataka, India"
 }

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac348979c1cb11f28595d48"),
"User" : "7829780519",
"Activity" : "Tracking",
"Date" : "2018-04-03",
"Time" : "14:35:52.245Z",
"LocationDetails" : "Banashankari 3rd Stage, Banashankari, Bengaluru, 
 Karnataka, India"
  }
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac38e599c1cb11f28595d4a"),
"User" : "7829780519",
"Activity" : "Tracking",
"Date" : "2018-04-03",
"Time" : "19:14:01.872Z",
"LocationDetails" : "Banashankari 3rd Stage, Banashankari, Bengaluru, 
Karnataka, India"
}

 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ac38e599c1cb11f28595d4b"),
 "User" : "7829780519",
 "Activity" : "Logout",
 "Date" : "2018-04-03",
 "Time" : "19:14:01.872Z",
 "LocationDetails" : "Banashankari 3rd Stage, Banashankari, Bengaluru, 
 Karnataka, India"
 }
```

Comment: Simple solution: `db.data.find({"Activity" : "Login"}).forEach(function(x){printjson(x);var out=db.data.findOne({"User" : x.User}); printjson(out); print("Logout time: "+out.Time);})`

Comment: Hai Thanks for Your reply....Actually i am passing Mobile No of user with Activity and i need all the data that is Between Login and Logout..